# ngRoute 403, access denied on own server

Tags: angularjs

When I try to access a template file which isn't in the same folder as my main template folder, I get an access denied error. How to fix this? My code is this:

```
disputairApp.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
    when('/dichtgetikt/disputair/test2/', {
        templateUrl: 'test/test.html',
        controller: 'userCtrl'
    }).
    otherwise({
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        //controller: 'userCtrl'
    });
}
]);
```

the "otherwise" does work, but the first one doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

When you attempt to go to the URL are you using the hash?

/#/dichtgetikt/disputair/test2/

See http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location and check the configuration section for options.

When I use "otherwise", I do it like this.

```
otherwise({redirectTo: '/whatever'});
```

Darryl